# "Gradle project refresh failed" and "URI not registered"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

"Gradle project refresh failed", is the error.

And when hover my mouse over "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", I get "URI not registered".

I've tried:

1) reinstalling android studio and android sdk tools.

2) I've tried changing the gradle directory from default to manually entering the directory of a downloaded gradle files.

3) Changing the shared VM options to 1024, and the option below it to -Xmx216m

And many other things...

But all in vain.

My android studio version is 3.0.1
Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your layout file location?

Comment: Try updating your gradle version to the latest one, i.e 4.6 and try once

Comment: did you uncheck the option of offline work in Global Gradle settings or not after giving path for gradle file?